# How to specify a parameter of a component in react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using React-router recently and found it was not that intuitive.
Here is my case. I defined a stateless React component "MainLayout" which has two parameters to include "headerBar" component and "children" component.

mainlayout.js:

```
const MainLayout = ({children,headerBar})=>{
  return (
    <div className="app">
      {headerBar}
      <main>
      {children}
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
export default MainLayout;
```

My routes are like this:

routes.js:

```
export default (
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route component={MainLayout}> -----> how to specify "headerBar"
      <Route path="/" component={Home} />

      <Route path="widgets">
        <Route component={SearchLayout}>
          <IndexRoute component={WidgetList} />
        </Route>
      </Route>

    </Route>
  </Router>
);
```

In such a case, how to specify "headerBar" in Route of "MainLayout"?

Thanks

Derek

Comment: Do you use any kind of state container? (Redux, flux ...)

Comment: @shota No, I did not use any container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With react router, you can declare multiple components in sub routes. This features is called [Named Components](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#named-components).

This topic has been treated here too: [Using React-Router with a layout page or multiple components per page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33062830/using-react-router-with-a-layout-page-or-multiple-components-per-page)

You should write somthing like:

```
<Route path="/" components={{body: Home, header: HeaderBar}} />
```

and

```
const MainLayout = ({body,header})=>{
  return (
    <div className="app">
      {header}
      <main>
      {body}
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Regards

Comment: I tried and it cannot work and got "warning.js:36Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `component` supplied to `Route`."

Comment: Which version of react router are you using?

Comment: it is 2.8.1  Thanks.

Comment: ok I think no a 's' is required in `component` from `<Route path="/" components={body: Home, header: HeaderBar} />`. I update my post