# Do not render certain components on certain routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

In my `index.js`, I have a render method with `Router` that contains `Route`s that show components:

```
<Router>
  <div>
    <Headers />
    <ToggleSwitch />
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/library" component={Library} />
    <Range />
  </div>
</Router>
```

This works fine.

However, on the `Library` route, I do not want to show either `<Headers />` or `<ToggleSwitch />`.

So I'd like to be able to apply the following approach, for example:

```
const isHeaderRoute = (!route.includes('library'))

{isHeaderRoute && (
  <Headers />
  <ToggleSwitch />
)}
```

To do this I would presumably need access to the URL path.

How can I achieve this using React Router?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Router v4 with multiple layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42862028/react-router-v4-with-multiple-layouts)

Answer (score 1):

```
<Router>
  <div>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/library" component={Library} />
    <Range />
  </div>
</Router>
```

Remove the `Headers` and `ToggleSwitch` component from the route and just put them in the `Home` Component.

If you want to do in the `Router` get the pathname by `window.location.pathname` and do what you have done in the example:

```
const isHeaderRoute = (!window.location.pathname.includes('library'))

{isHeaderRoute && (
  <Headers />
  <ToggleSwitch />
)}
```

`window.location.pathname` is a Javascript method, not a react-router method. What you have suggested is impossible in react-router because the check needs to be done outside the router where there is no way of accessing the router path which can only be accessed inside the router (by child components etc).

Answer (score 1):

I just came across the same issue, solving it with the same kind of answer [as posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42862028/react-router-v4-with-multiple-layouts)

Wrap your `<Route />` in a component that includes the `<Headers />` and `<ToggleSwitch />` (or vice versa, which ever makes more sense for your code)

Eg. (ES6 using `react-router-v4`)

```
const SpecialRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }: {component: any}) => (
  <div>
    <Headers />
    <ToggleSwitch />
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props: {location: string}) => (
        <Component {...props} />
      )}
    />
  </div>
)

<Router>
  <div>
    <SpecialRoute exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/library" component={Library} />
    <Range />
  </div>
</Router>
```

[Further reading](https://simonsmith.io/reusing-layouts-in-react-router-4/)