# React Router Changes URL, but BrowserRouter doesn't change Viewed Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

The project I am working on is kinda of sensitive, but here's what I have that I can show you all.

[image: The Default Domain]

When I click on one of the s in my NavBar, it changes the URL, but it does not change the view to the proper component. Does anyone have any idea why? If there's a better way I can phrase this or improve the quality of my questin, let me know.

**My render that I return**

```
<NavBar />
<BrowserRouter>
  <div>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/propertytypes" component={PropertyTypes} />
      <Route path="/entitytypes" component={EntityTypes} />
      <Route path="/associationtypes" component={AssociationTypes} />
      <Route path={Routes.ROOT} component={Test} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

**My NavBar**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class NavBar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/propertytypes">Props!</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/entitytypes">Ent!</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/associationtypes">Ass!</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default NavBar;
```

**After clicking Props link**
[image]

Comment: Are you really using BrowserRouter? But, what I see is HashRouter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Besides what @Ukasyah noticed about disparity between the Router you are using (you say you are using `BrowserRouter`) and the screen captures with the URL you are getting (that points out you are using `HashRouter`), you must be getting a problem with the code you are showing up because the `<Link>` component in order to work must be contained inside the `BrowserRouter`. In your browser console it must be happening this error:

> Warning: Failed context type: The context `router` is marked as
>   required in `Link`, but its value is `undefined`.

So to avoid the problem and links start to work, your render should be something like this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div>
    <NavBar />
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/propertytypes" component={PropertyTypes} />
      <Route path="/entitytypes" component={EntityTypes} />
      <Route path="/associationtypes" component={AssociationTypes} />
      <Route path={Routes.ROOT} component={Test} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Note that I put the `NavBar` component inside the `div` because `BrowserRouter` only allows to have a single child.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was wondering why it wasn't working as intended. I ended up putting it inside the <div> of my BrowserRouter and it worked out find. react-router no longer uses hash thought correct?

Comment: Yes, they still have the option to use [HashRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter) but you have to remember it doesn't connect well with the browser history.

Comment: This was the key for me: ```Note that I put the NavBar component inside the div because BrowserRouter only allows to have a single child.```

Answer (score 4):

I have been looking at different SO questions to solve this issue and none of them helped. My problem was using BrowserRouter in multiple different components. Same as [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4975#issuecomment-344449879).

Answer (score 1):

For me, the issue was that my entire app was wrapped with a `<Router>`, because that was how the boilerplate code was set up. Then I was copying snips from BrowserRouter docs, and did not remove the `<BrowserRouter>` wrapper around the code. Nested routers won't work properly.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake I made was, I started with the setup from the documentation, which involves using:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
```

Then I started splitting everything into separate layout files like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43826525/413785). So I initially copied the whole import between multiple files. At some point I was cleaning up the code and realized I only needed to import the `Switch` but I foolishly forgot to remove the `BrowserRouter as`, and I ended up with:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Switch } from "react-router-dom";
```

Which is obviously wrong since it mapped BrowserRouter to Switch, you can't have nested BrowserRouter 's and that's what introduced the issue in my case.

Comment: This following isn't a fix, but I'd recommend trying out NextJS. Makes routing a lot more simple.

Comment: Agreed. I just thought whoever is searching for "url updating, but view isn't" might see this and hopefully it helps if they made the same mistake I did.