# <Link> only changes the url when click but not the components and the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have problem with my app. In my header i have Twitter, Youtube, Instgram which is if i click one of them it will show the page from the component. Example if i click instagram it will load Instagram Component and change the page to Instagram. But in my app, after i click one of them the pages not changes and not load the component but the url changes. This is my code :

```
import React from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import { Row, Col, Card, Layout, Spin } from "antd";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import cubejs from "@cubejs-client/core";
import { QueryRenderer } from "@cubejs-client/react";
import { Line, Bar, Pie } from "react-chartjs-2";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Facebook from "./Facebook";
import Youtube from "./Youtube";
import Instagram from "./Instagram";
import Twitter from "./Twitter";
import moment from "moment";

const AppLayout = ({ children }) => (
  <Layout>
    <Layout.Header>
      <div
        style={{
          float: "left"
        }}
      >
        <h2
          style={{
            color: "#fff",
            margin: 0
          }}
        >
          NARASIDATA
        </h2>
      </div>
      <Router>
        <div
          style={{
            float: "right"
          }}
        >
          <Link to="/facebook/" component={Facebook}>
              <h2
                style={{
                  color: "#fff",
                  margin: 0,
                  paddingLeft: 50
                }}
                >
                  Facebook
              </h2>
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div
          style={{
            float: "right"
          }}
        >
          <Link to="/instagram/">
              <h2
                style={{
                  color: "#fff",
                  margin: 0,
                  paddingLeft: 50
                }}
              >
                Instagram
              </h2>
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div
          style={{
            float: "right"
          }}
        >
          <Link to="/youtube/">
              <h2
                style={{
                  color: "#fff",
                  margin: 0,
                  paddingLeft: 50
                }}
              >
                Youtube
              </h2>
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div
          style={{
            float: "right"
          }}
        >
          <Link to="/twitter/">
              <h2
                style={{
                  color: "#fff",
                  margin: 0,
                  paddingLeft: 50
                }}
              >
                Twitter
              </h2>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </Layout.Header>
    <Layout.Content
      style={{
        padding: "0 25px 25px 25px",
        margin: "25px"
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </Layout.Content>
  </Layout>
);

const Dashboard = ({ children }) => (
  <Row type="flex" justify="space-around" align="top" gutter={24}>
    {children}
  </Row>
);

const DashboardItem = ({ children, title }) => (
  <Col span={24} lg={12}>
    <Card
      title={title}
      style={{
        marginBottom: "24px"
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </Card>
  </Col>
);

const COLORS_SERIES = ["#FF6492", "#141446", "#7A77FF"];

const lineRender = ({ resultSet }) => {
  const data = {
    labels: resultSet.categories().map(c => c.category),
    datasets: resultSet.series().map((s, index) => ({
      label: s.title,
      data: s.series.map(r => r.value),
      borderColor: COLORS_SERIES[index],
      fill: false
    }))
  };
  const options = {};
  return <Line data={data} options={options} />;
};

const API_URL = "http://localhost:4000";
const cubejsApi = cubejs(
  "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE1NjI4MjQ2NjYsImV4cCI6MTU2MjkxMTA2Nn0.h9s4qtiFSia8vHqtyYNwkJDihh-_NcCD57wozOmmz4k",
  {
    apiUrl: API_URL + "/cubejs-api/v1"
  }
);

const renderChart = Component => ({ resultSet, error }) =>
  (resultSet && <Component resultSet={resultSet} />) ||
  (error && error.toString()) || <Spin />;

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AppLayout>
        <Dashboard>
          <DashboardItem>
          <Router>
            <Route exact path="/twitter/" component={Twitter} />
            <Route exact path="/youtube/" component={Youtube} />
            <Route exact path="/instagram/" component={Instagram} />
            <Route exact path="/facebook/" component={Facebook} />
          </Router>
            <QueryRenderer
              query={{
                measures: ["Twitter.retweetcount"],
                timeDimensions: [
                  {
                    dimension: "Twitter.publishat",
                    granularity: "day",
                    dateRange: "This month"
                  }
                ],
                filters: [
                  {
                    dimension: "Twitter.username",
                    operator: "equals",
                    values: ["narasitv"]
                  }
                ]
              }}
              cubejsApi={cubejsApi}
              render={renderChart(lineRender)}
            />
          </DashboardItem>
        </Dashboard>
      </AppLayout>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

What's the problem in my app?
I am new in react.

Comment: Remove "exact " from all except home page.

Comment: Still same not working

Comment: Why do you have `Link` tags surrounded by a `Router`?

Comment: I just followed https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link

Comment: You don't understand how Routes and Links work.

Comment: Your `<Link>`s and `<Route>`s have to be wrapped by the same `<Router>` element.

Comment: Here's a version with greatly shortened navigation code: https://codesandbox.io/s/still-cloud-u313c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Router Changes URL, but BrowserRouter doesn't change Viewed Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51461153/react-router-changes-url-but-browserrouter-doesnt-change-viewed-component)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should only have one `<Router />` so remove the one around your links in `AppLayout` and wrap your whole `App` render in `<Router />` like this:

```
<Router>
  <AppLayout>
    <Route />
    <Route />
    // ...
  </AppLayout>
</Router>
```

Also you should replace `Router` by a `BrowserRouter` https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter