# Dynamic parameters with template regions

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

Trying to set up a react app with React-Router v4.
I require navigation with a dynamic route param, and the ability to target areas of my app template with a component that takes the dynamic route param. According to the v4 docs, I need to define my routes like this:

```
const routes = [
    {
        exact: true,
        path: '/vpcs',
        navLevel2: () => <VpcList></VpcList>,
        mainContent: () => <h1>Hello VPCs</h1>
    },
    {
        exact: true,
        path: '/vpcs/:vpcName',
        navLevel2: () => <VpcList></VpcList>,
        mainContent: () => <Vpc></Vpc>
    }
]
```

Then I can do:

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/">    
    <div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><NavLink to="/vpcs">Vpcs</NavLink></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <nav>
            {routes.map((route, index) => (
              <Route
                key={index}
                path={route.path}
                exact={route.exact}
                component={route.navLevel2}
              />
            ))}
        </nav>
        <main>
            {routes.map((route, index) => (
              <Route
                key={index}
                path={route.path}
                exact={route.exact}
                component={route.mainContent}
              />
            ))}
        </main>         
    </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

However, it seems there's no way to pass the value for `:vpcName` to the `Vpc` component, which requires it. When I hit the route `/vpc/my-vpc-name` the console logs

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined at new Vpc ...
```

To see what I have to work with, in place of `component={route.mainContent}` I've tried:

```
component={() => (<p>{JSON.stringify(arguments)}</p>)}
```

And that yielded

```
{"0":{"i":480,"l":false,"exports":{}},"1":{}}
```

...which is not encouraging.

What do I do? Do I need to rewind to v3 to get template regions to work while ueing dynamic route params??

Comment: I made a tiny example with the code that you posted: https://codesandbox.io/s/v61p95k850 try typing: /vpcs/3452 in the small browser and you will see it working

Comment: @knowbody: That worked. Please enter this as an answer so I can upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your component actually receives the params via props, you are just not using them. Try doing something like: `mainContent: props => <div>{props.match.params.vpcName}</div>`

I made a small example for you here: https://codesandbox.io/s/v61p95k850

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `component` in your `<Route>` tag, you should be using `render` which takes the function and you can then use your function like `{() => (<p>{JSON.stringify(arguments)}</p>)}` inside it.

[Here is a link to their doc](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func)